# Using localStorage value as attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I want to use localStorage value as attribute selector

```
$("#lf_options input[value=WYSIWYG]").attr("checked", true);
```

works fine, however when I try to use localStorage value nothing happens

```
$("#lf_options input[value=" + localStorage.viewMode + "]").attr("checked", true);
```

this way neither

```
$("#lf_options input[value=" + localStorage["viewMode"] + "]").attr("checked", true);
```

localStorage["viewMode"] is indeed set to "WYSIWYG"

What am I missing?

**EDIT: I misspelled WYSIWYG while typing the post but it's not a problem**

Comment: `console.log(localStorage.getItem('viewMode'));` <- What value does this display in the console?

Comment: Also `checked` is a property, not an attribute. I think the above will work but you should consider switching it out for the more appropriate `.prop('checked', true);`. For more information see [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)...

Comment: The value in your viewMode variable ("WYSIWIG") seems to differ from the value you are checkin in your first statement ("WISYWIG")

Comment: `WYSIWYG` is short for `What You See Is What You Get`, so both versions are misspelled :)

Comment: `What I See You Wouldnt Imagine Getting` -  a new paradigm in visual editors

Comment: I misspelled WYSIWYG while typing the post but it's not a problem guys! I swapped .attr with .prop but in vain.

console.log(localStorage.getItem('viewMode')); ---> WYSIWYG

Answer (score 0):

1. As a general rule, use `prop` instead of `attr` for `checked` properties.
2. If an attribute name contain special characters (including space), you need quotes around that too:

try this:

```
$("#lf_options input[value='" + localStorage.viewMode + "']").prop("checked", true);
```

If the value could have somehow gained whitespace you may also need to trim the value:

```
$("#lf_options input[value='" + $.trim(localStorage.viewMode) + "']").prop("checked", true);
```

3. As @Markai says, the example you gave has misstyped `WISYWIG` vs `WYSIWYG`, which is a simple typo. `WYSIWYG` is short for `What You See Is What You Get`, so both versions are misspelled :)

*Failing all this, please provide a sample of your page HTML, so we can run tests (e.g. in a JSFiddle)*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j0pvekt5/

Here it works fine, but when I integrate it into chrome extension it does nothing

Comment: @Giorgio L: That fiddle works. Is it a specific browser?